# What does com.sun.el package contain?

Tags: jsf, weblogic, el, oracle-adf

Is this just an API defined by Java, to be implemented by (say) servers, or the JRE includes the implementation too?

Thing is that I was trying to concatenate two strings using '+' on my JSF page, but it threw NumberFormatException. It seems it was trying to parse my strings using Long.parseLong().

I was surprised to see this package in the stack trace, as I was thought these expressions are Groovy expressions. This certainly doesn't seem to be Groovy but some other EL.

I am using Weblogic server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It contains Sun's **implementation** of the [`javax.el`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/package-summary.html) API which is specified by [EL specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html). This API is part of Java EE, not Java SE. Implementors are required to provide a concrete implementation of the abstract API so that all the API-definied works will be done. Java EE is basically one large *abstract* specification. The servletcontainers / applicationservers like Weblogic, Tomcat, Glassfish, etc offers the *concrete* implementations.

As to your actual problem, no, you indeed can't concatenate strings in EL using `+` operator like that. The `+` operator in EL assumes the both sides to be a `Number`, for round numbers that's `Long`. That's specified in the EL specification.

You can however just use multiple expressions like follows to "concat" strings.

```
<h:outputText value="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}" />
```

Comment: In my case the string concatenation is tricky. I have en EL expression like - #{condition? string1: string2+string3} . So I need an el function for concatenation, since + is not an option.

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{string1}" rendered="#{condition}" /><h:outputText value="#{string2}#{string3}" rendered="#{!condition}" />`